# regex with dependent condition

Tags: regex

I want to match any "**b7**" with **$** insert. **\$*b\$*7** should match :

```
b7
b$7
$b7
$b$7
```

Other rule :
it can be preceded with anything except **A-Z** or **a-z** . Also there is dependent rule : if it's preceded by '**!**' (exclamation mark) then the word preceding the '**!**' has to be 'matrix'. For example , it should match :

```
b7
= b7
matrix!b7
ok?b7
_b7
```

and shoud not match :

```
bb7
ok!b7
= !b7
!b7
```

I use this :

```
((matrix!)|[^A-Za-z!]|^)\$*b\$*7(\D|$)
```

It seems to work fine, until i put the $ in front of b. For example it should not match  **shot!b7** but if add $ in front of b -> **shot!$b7** , now it matches and it's not what i want. I want if there is '**!**' then it has to be **matrix!**.

Comment: Which regex flavour are you using? In particular, does it support lookarounds?

Comment: It matches `shot!$b7` because `$` is included in the character set allowed. The captured group would be different but you can replace the character set with `[^A-Za-z!$]` and all the examples you showed us work.

Comment: @Aaron i'm using regex in google sheet.

Comment: @MarcoLuzzara i think it should not match because there is '!' in front of it. "shot!" should already make it invalid.

Comment: So, whenever you have a `!` (does not matter the position), the regex is correct only if that `!` is appended to `matrix`, right? `something!bla_b7` should not match, am I correct?

Comment: @MarcoLuzzara yes, so it shouldn't matches shot!$b7 .

Comment: From the description you have given you are wrong, it should match `shot!$b7` because `b7` is prepended by something different from `[A-Za-z!]`. That is why I told you that putting a `$` in the character set would solve the problem. The solution you have accepted matches the case I gave you, but it should not. You should have written that the position of `!` matters and that it should always be prepended by `matrix`, not only when it is put before `b7`. Hope to be clear, otherwise I can write you an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your regex engine supports variable-width lookbehinds you can use the following :

```
(?<=[^A-Za-z!$]|matrix!)\$*b\$*7
```

The lookbehind makes sure that the b7 with optional `$` isn't preceded by a letter and that if it is preceded by an exclamation point this one is itself preceded by "matrix".

You can [try it here](https://regex101.com/r/HS6X8V/1).

Answer (score 1):

Your pattern matches `shot!$b7` because this part in the alternation `[^A-Za-z!]` does allow `$`

As `\$*` matches optional dollar signs, it can match `$b7` in `shot!$b7`

---

You could exclude the dollar sign from matching as well, and the value is in capture group 1.

```
(?:matrix!|[^a-zA-Z\n!$]|^)(\$*b\$*7)\b
```

**Explanation**

- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `matrix!` Match literally
  - `|` Or
  - `[^a-zA-Z\n!$]` Match any char other than the listed chars
  - `|` Or
  - `^` Start of string
- `)` Close non capture group
- `(\$*b\$*7)` Capture **group 1**, match b7 between optional dollar signs
- `\b`A word boundary to prevent a partial match

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZJQqZx/1)